# Is it possible to disable md-dialog resize in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, mddialog

Is it possible to disable dialog resizing in Angular JS?
I've googled a lot and still does not see any solution for that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems, its possible but via a hucky way.

```
<style>
    md-dialog.disableVerticalScrollbar {
        max-height: unset !important;
}
</style>

<md-dialog class="disableVerticalScrollbar">
...
```